# reading heading from docx file using python

Tags: python-2.7, docx

i want to read heading from a docx file but Document module does not have property of read heading how i can do that

```
from docx import Document
def docheading():
    document = Document('C://Users//yousafzai//Desktop//Database//riya//riya//AbdulMateen.docx')
    headings=document.heading
```

Answer (score 2):

I kinda did the same thing. I did something like this the attribute you are looking for is Style.name

```
for paragraph in paragraphs:
    if paragraph.style.name=='Heading 1':
        print (paragraph.text)
```

Comment: if "Heading" in paragraph.style.name in second line can fetch all the heading in the document.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can extract the title:

```
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    if paragraph.style.name=='Title':
        doc_title = paragraph.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a different library, for example paradocx, which can read paradata from the Office XML spec using something like `style='Heading 1'`

Comment: can you explain a bit more